# Unable to remove CLI library packages

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, raspbian, mono

I was installing some packages and during the install of one, the system hung and the package was not installed. But, the package was added to the list of installed packages. So, I restart the system and I try the following:

- When I try to remove the package, it doesn't work because it can't find a config file.
- When I try to install the package, it says the package is already installed, and therefore won't install it
- When I try to update, it tries to remove the package, and encounters the error above.

So, my question is asking if there's a way to manually remove a package from the list of installed packages, or is there another way to solve this problem?

When I run: `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Error is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libglade2.0-cil libglib2.0-cil libgtk2.0-cil
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
18 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 2,819 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 119043 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libglade2.0-cil (2.12.26-0xamarin1) ...
E: File does not exist: /usr/share/cli-common/packages.d/policy.2.8.glade-sharp.installcligac
dpkg: error processing package libglade2.0-cil (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing libgtk2.0-cil (2.12.26-0xamarin1) ...
E: File does not exist: /usr/share/cli-common/packages.d/policy.2.6.gtk-dotnet.installcligac
dpkg: error processing package libgtk2.0-cil (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing libglib2.0-cil (2.12.26-0xamarin1) ...
E: File does not exist: /usr/share/cli-common/packages.d/policy.2.6.glib-sharp.installcligac
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-cil (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglade2.0-cil
 libgtk2.0-cil
 libglib2.0-cil
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What if you just create the missing file. Does that make the post-removal script happy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to try.

The first is to fix `/usr/share/cli-common/policy-remove` so it doesn’t fail if the policy is absent: edit its last line so that it runs `rm -f` instead of `rm`. That *should* allow the packages to be removed correctly.

If that fails, and since you’re trying to remove all the Mono packages, it should be safe enough to remove the failing `postrm` scripts:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/lib{glade,glib,gtk}2.0-cil.postrm
```

The only operation the `postrm` scripts do is unregister the policies, which you don’t care about since you’re removing everything anyway.

You’re not the only person to have suffered from this issue: it was reported in 2012 as [Debian bug 692962](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=692962).